# Is this composite function differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is the function $$ \log \log |\sin x|$$ differentiable? How can I justify the answer?

Comment: For a start, you could try to figure out where it is even defined.

Comment: Where does $x$ live?  As a real-valued function, $|\sin(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$, which implies that $\log|\sin(x)| \le 0$, which implies that $\log(\log|\sin(x)|)$ is not real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ can be complex and defined appropriately, the Chain Rule would work to produce the derivative in a reasonable sense.

If $x$ is intended to be real, however, since $\log |\sin x| < 1$, the function is undefined, and hence not differentiable.